# Create 3 dimensional grid two elements, one element in one row but in random columns

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I've created a 3 dimensional grid.  I have two separate objects filling the spaces of this grid.  I want to have one of the objects in one row but on randomly selected columns.

Has anyone done this before or can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using Unity and C#.  Thank you.

```
    Vector3 towerSize = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);

//create grid tower
for (int x = 0; x < towerSize.x; x++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < towerSize.z; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < towerSize.y; y++)
        {
            //spawn tiles and space them
            GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(tiles);
            obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x * 1.2f, y * 1.2f, z * 1.2f);

            //add them all to a List
            allTiles.Add(obj);
            obj.name = "tile " + allTiles.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

There is the code for the grid.  I tried to have two objects in a singular List move to those tiles but the random column objects get in the same columns when I do that with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCubes.Count; i++)
{
    allCubes[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
        allCubes[i].transform.position,
        allTiles[i].transform.position, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Then thought put the two types of cubes in separate Lists themselves.  Which ended up being even more messy.  haha  Does posting that code help?

Comment: Can you post the your relevant code here? We won't know how to fix your code without seeing it.

Comment: It has comments all over the place.  haha  Let me clean it up a bit and paste it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is number of cubes the same as number of grids? In what aspect does the code snippet above provide any randomness? In fact, what goal are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an extremely old question of mine.  It was a project that got canceled.  I randomly came across it and out of curiosity I decided to try to complete this particular issue I was having such trouble doing back then.  And I did.

```
public Vector3 towerSize = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);

    public GameObject tiles;
    public GameObject randomTile;

//public variables for debugging purposes.
//no real need to be seen in inspector in final.  cleaner too if they're hidden
    public int randomSelectedTile;

    public List<GameObject> allTiles;

    void Start()
    {
        //create grid tower
        for (int x = 0; x < towerSize.x; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < towerSize.z; z++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < towerSize.y; y++)
                {
                    //spawn cubes and space them
                    GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(tiles);
                    obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x * 1.2f, y * 1.2f, z * 1.2f);

                    //add them all to a List
                    allTiles.Add(obj);
                    obj.name = "tile " + allTiles.Count;
                }
            }
        }

        //select a random cube in the list
        randomSelectedTile = Random.Range(0, allTiles.Count);

        //get the cube object to delete
        GameObject deleteObj = allTiles.ElementAt(randomSelectedTile);
        //spawn the random cube at the position of the cube we will delete
        GameObject rndObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(randomTile);
        rndObj.transform.position = deleteObj.transform.position;

        //remove the element at that location
        allTiles.RemoveAt(randomSelectedTile);
        //insert the random cube at that element's location
        allTiles.Insert(randomSelectedTile, rndObj);

        //destroy the unwanted cube
        Destroy(deleteObj);
    }
```

It's nice to see how you've improved over time.  Just in case anyone else would benefit from the solution.  Again, I apologize for bringing it back up.